# Glossary Web application

Tags: web-apps, collaboration, knowledge-organization

I need to create a collaborative glossary for a project of mine, and was wondering whether there was already a ready-to-use lightweight glossary / dictionary web application that I can put on my web server and start working with it.

To be more specific on my needs: I am leading a project that involves concepts that are too specific and technical, so it would help my team to have a central point where they can register definitions to these concepts for them or other teammates to look up later. That is, a simple dictionary, ideally where terms can be linked to other terms.

I tried googling it, but the search terms are tricky since all I end up with is actual glossaries defining what a 'web application' is.

I have tried https://code.google.com/p/live-glossary/ but it's giving me lots of headaches, so I thought about switching to something else.

The only thing I require is that I can run it on a regular Apache Server or a Java container (i.e. Tomcat) and for it to be free to use.

PS. I know I can use any generic CMS to create a glossary. I just want a simple, quick and lightweight solution.